# How to use Mono's XBUILD on VSTS?

Tags: c#, mono, azure-devops

How can I use **[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/)'s XBUILD** on *VSTS*?

I checked the hosted agent capabilities and didn't see it in there.

> You may find your agent capabilities at https://???.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool?poolId=2&_a=agents
>   and *click* to **Capabilities**
>
> *(make sure you change the ??? part with yours)*

Comment: Why did you down vote a legit question without even typing a comment about what is your concern?  Be responsible here and state your concern then give a chance to fix it **before** you down vote it please.  Thanks in advance

Comment: As Xamarin is piloting MSBuild in its product line in latest build, I wonder if there is still a need to use `xbuild`.

Comment: There will be because there are still projects out there written on Mono.

Comment: I definitely talked about MSBuild on Mono. What else have I said?

Comment: I thought you were talking about Xamarin products (such as studio etc) and not the Mono directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mono is not available in VSTS Hosted agent. You can vote [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16363675-include-mono-in-vsts-hosted-agent) user voice.

The workaround is that, you can setup a [new build agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows) on your machine.

1. Go to Agent pools control panel tab (In admin page of team project/team
2. Click Download agent
3. Click Windows
4. Click Download button
5. Run Command prompt and go to that agent location
6. Run .\config.cmd

You can add mono to the environment variable in order to run mono command directly.

1. Open Environment Variable window (System Properties=>Advanced=>Environment Variables)
2. Click New to add System variable (mono:[mono installation path, e.g. C:\Program\Mono]
3. Select Path in System Variables list=>Edit
4. Add ;%mono%\bin
   After that, you can add Command Line step/task to your build definition to call mono command. For example: Tool: mono, Argument: --version